# how do I add array in object property in another array as parameter in function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

i tried to make a function for averaging all the array in an object of another array, but however i tried i can't call the parameter for the function i make

> 

```
let students = [randy, riziq, rama];
let randy = {
  name: 'Randy',
  score: [75, 80, 90]
};
let riziq = {
    name: 'Riziq',
    score: [50, 90, 90]
};
let rama = {
    name: 'Rama',
    score: [80, 75, 90]
};

function average(/*students*/) {
    let avgScore = /*students's score avg*/ 
return /*students's name + "" + student's average*/ 
};

console.log(average(/*students*/));
```

is there any way to call that?

i tried to make a for loop to each of the props inside the students array but still i can't call that.
i tried to sum all the student's score with array.reduce() of the students array and divide them with array.length

Comment: Do you have any errors in your dev console? Maybe something like: _"ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'randy' before initialization"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `let students = [randy, riziq, rama];` after the declaration of variables.

```js
let randy = {
  name: 'Randy',
  score: [75, 80, 90]
};
let riziq = {
    name: 'Riziq',
    score: [50, 90, 90]
};
let rama = {
    name: 'Rama',
    score: [80, 75, 90]
};

let students = [randy, riziq, rama];

function average(students) {
    return students.map(({name, score}) => {
    const total = score.reduce((a, b) => a + b,0);
    return `${name} ${total/score.length}`;
});
}

console.log(average(students));
```

Learn more about [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: You may also want to add in links to the MDN documentation for `map` and `reduce` in case the OP has never come across them before.

Comment: thanks for guidance, i'll try to continue my journey

Answer (score 0):

```js
let randy = {
             name: 'Randy',
             score: [75, 80, 90]
            };
let riziq = {
             name: 'Riziq',
             score: [50, 90, 90]
            };
let rama =  {
             name: 'Rama',
             score: [80, 75, 90]
            };
            let students = [randy, riziq, rama];
            
function average(students) {
    var data = { "averages" : {}};
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < students.length; ++i) {
        var total = 0;
        for (var ti = 0; ti < students[i].score.length; ti++) {
            total += students[i].score[ti] << 0;
        }
        var avg = total/students[i].score.length;
                    
        data.averages[i] = { 
                            "name":students[i].name,  
                            "average":avg.toFixed(2),  
                           }; 
     }
                
     return data;
};
            
console.log(average(students));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).